# Specflow Lifecycle of feature context

Tags: c#, specflow, xunit

I've the following code snippet

```
public class BaseSteps : Steps
{
    [BeforeFeature]
    public static BeforeFeatureStep()
    {
        var otherStep = new OtherStep();
        otherStep.ExecuteStep();
    }
} 

public class OtherStep : Steps
{
    [Given("I save (.*) against (.*)]
    public void ExecuteStep(string val, string key) 
    {
        this.FeatureContext.Add(key, val);
    }
}
```

Feature File 1

```
Scenario: S1
Given I save 10 against A

Scenario: S2
Given I save 20 against B
```

Feature File 2

```
Scenario: S3 
Given I save 30 against C
```

Now, the test order is determined by the test runner and is haphazard.
So, if the order of execution of scenarios is S1 -> S3 -> S2, shouldn't I be able to access the key value pair saved in scenario S1 in its feature context from scenario S2 (as both belong to the same feature)?

I agree that scenarios should be independent, but my requirement needs me to do some setup per feature and if already done, skip it. With the above approach I'm not able to do it because the key value pair saved in the feature context from scenario S1 is not available in scenario S2

Answer (score 0):

> I agree that scenarios should be independent, but my requirement needs me to do some setup per feature and if already done, skip it.

This should be handled by your `Given` so you don't need to worry about that from the Scenario's perspective. Any setup common to all three scenarios should go in a `Background`:

```
Background:
    Given I save 10 against A

Scenario: S1
    When...
    Then...

Scenario: S2
    Given I save 20 against B
    When...
    Then...

Scenario: S3
    Given I save 20 against B
    And I save 30 against C
    When...
    Then...
```

The step definition for "Given I save X against Y" should contain the code necessary to check for the condition, and then not apply it again.

Comment: I agree background is to be used for common setup.
But in the requirement I have, my scenarios have to be compulsorily placed in different feature files for the purpose of logical classification. How do I handle it in such a case?

Comment: @DevD: Each scenario needs it's own proper setup. You'll have to put in all the necessary `Given`'s for each scenario.